# Extract Google Analytics Data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics

I have set up the Google analytics API on Google sheets for reporting purposes, however have had some issues:

1. How to add titles to the table?

```
function myFunction() {
    var tableId = 'ga:*******' // Your Google Analytics view ID
    var startDate = '2daysAgo';
    var endDate = '1daysAgo';
    var metric = 'ga:pageviews';
    var options = {
      'dimensions': 'ga:pageTitle, ga:date',
      'sort': '-ga:date',
      'filters': 'ga:pageTitle==(EN) SignUp Page'
    };

    var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric, options); // Make the request
  
    var total_sessions = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions'];
    var total_transactions = result.totalsForAllResults['ga:transactions'];
  
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Current document
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Current sheet
  
    //sheet.getRange('B3').setValue(total_sessions); // Write total sessions
    //sheet.getRange('B4').setValue(total_transactions); // Write toal transactions
  
    var rows = result.rows;
  
    for (var k = 0; k < rows.length; k++) {

        var pagetitle= rows[k][0];
        var date= rows[k][1];
        var pageviews= rows[k][2];

        var result_row = [pagetitle, date, pageviews]; // Single row of results

        sheet.appendRow(result_row); // Print single row of results
    }
}
```

Comment: What table? Can you provide an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sheet.appendRow` to add desired header row before looping through report rows.